# Reset counter value within new paragraph

Tags: counters

The `\newcounter{<counter-name>}[<outer-counter>]` commands will define a new counter. For example, `\newcounter{example}[section]`
command creates a new counter called `example` that will be reset every time the **section** counter is increased.

But for **paragraph** counter, the `\newcounter{<counter-name>}[paragraph]` doesn't work.

Here is the MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}


\newcounter{sentencenum}[paragraph]
\newcommand{\sno}[0]{\refstepcounter{sentencenum}$_{\arabic{sentencenum}}$}


\begin{document}


\sno{}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
\sno{}Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
\sno{}Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuerid, vulputate a, magna.
\sno{}Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus etnetus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
\sno{}Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem.
\sno{}Nulla et lectusvestibulum urna fringilla ultrices.
\sno{}Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat.
\sno{}Integer sapien est,iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc.
\sno{}Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum.
\sno{}Aenean faucibus.
\sno{}Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla.
\sno{}Curabitur auctor semper nulla.
\sno{}Donec variusorci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orcidignissim rutrum.



%
% Bug: The second paragraph should reset the counter value of `sentencenum` since here start a new paragraph
%
\sno{}Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi.
\sno{}Morbi auctor lorem non justo.
\sno{}Namlacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus.
\sno{}Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum,erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi.
\sno{}Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.
Suspendisseut massa.


\end{document}
```

Comment: In your document you not use `\paragraph{<title>}` ...

Comment: @Zarko ... he possibly means to make the counter zero between the paragraphs of the text and not the sectioning command `\paragraph`.

Comment: @koleygr, I understood what OP want, I only note him that his approach will not work since he doesn't use `\paragraph{...} titles. Possible solution gives your answer

Comment: Ok @Zarko... Thanks for the reply ... Although I first tried with a \paragraph command to make sure it would work ... but may be some depth should added too or renewing the command paragraph should be needed too,

Comment: The name of the `\paragraph` command is misleading you. It is not executed when a paragraph is started. It’s very unfortunate that Leslie Lamport chose it to mean `\subsubsubsection`.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say that this is a recommended way to do that but could solve this problem.
Please test it in more complex documents because I can't really know the side effects. Here is the code on your example:

```
\documentclass{article}



\newcounter{sentencenum}
\newcommand{\sno}[0]{\refstepcounter{sentencenum}$_{\arabic{sentencenum}}$}

\let\oldpar\par
\def\par{\setcounter{sentencenum}{0}\oldpar}


\begin{document}


\sno{}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
\sno{}Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
\sno{}Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuerid, vulputate a, magna.
\sno{}Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus etnetus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
\sno{}Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem.
\sno{}Nulla et lectusvestibulum urna fringilla ultrices.
\sno{}Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat.
\sno{}Integer sapien est,iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc.
\sno{}Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum.
\sno{}Aenean faucibus.
\sno{}Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla.
\sno{}Curabitur auctor semper nulla.
\sno{}Donec variusorci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orcidignissim rutrum.



%
% Bug: The second paragraph should reset the counter value of `sentencenum` since here start a new paragraph
%
\sno{}Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi.
\sno{}Morbi auctor lorem non justo.
\sno{}Namlacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus.
\sno{}Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum,erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi.
\sno{}Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.
Suspendisseut massa.


\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is:

For every new paragraph in latex, the `\par` command is executed. So, I added the functionality of making zero your counter by redefining `\par` (seems dangerous to me in first thinking about... but MAY BE it is ok....)

PS: Paragraph of text is created with empty lines between text ... But there is a sectioning command `\paragraph` too that you "tried to use" by mistake in your MWE.